# Why is MatLab breaking for certain variable inputs?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, error-handling

here's my code:

```
function test(n)
r = (0:1000)/n;
Phi = 2*pi*r;
[x,y] = pol2cart(Phi,r);
plot(x,y)
end
```

here's the output for n = 100,10,1 in that order:
[image]

what's happening with the last graph? Why is it freaking out? >.> ...

more fun shapes after n = 1:
here n = 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically, the right most one should connect the points (n,0) where n is a natural number between 0 and 1000. Due to floating point precision, it is slightly off the 0 and get's very small values close to zero for the y-value. Please notice the 10^-x (can't read the x because it is to small) which indicates the scale for the y-axes. These are very small numbers.

For any values <4 it is nearly impossible to recognize the original spiral, here is a plot which shows the inner 20 revolutions for four different n values.

[image]

For any small value of n you will see an output similar to n=0.01 but for any large n it's just some aliasing which is either a line (which looks rough because of precision errors if you zoom in enough) or some spiral.

Code used to plot:

```
r = 0:.01:20;
Phi = 2*pi*r;
[x,y] = pol2cart(Phi,r);
plot(x,y,'r')
hold on
r = 0:.9:20;
Phi = 2*pi*r;
[x,y] = pol2cart(Phi,r);
plot(x,y,'g')
r = 0:1:20;
Phi = 2*pi*r;
[x,y] = pol2cart(Phi,r);
plot(x,y,'b')
r = 0:1.1:20;
Phi = 2*pi*r;
[x,y] = pol2cart(Phi,r);
plot(x,y,'black')
legend({'0.01','.9','1','1.1'})
```

Comment: i don't understand... n = 1.1 works and n = 0.9 works ... what's wrong with n = 1 or n = 1.0?

Comment: I added some explanations.

Comment: interesting .... i think i kinda get it ... is there a way to output the graph with a interactive slider so that I could modulate the value of `n` and see how the graph changes in real time?

Comment: Use `uicontrol`, it's explained here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html